# CMake Xcode generator - add capability "hardened runtime"

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

Problem is quite simple. I have multi platform project (`Windows`/`Mac OS`).

Now in case of `Mac OS` I need to enable "Hardened runtime" in capabilities section of my bundle (it is launchd daemon).

I wish my Xcode project is generated by `cmake` (I don't want to maintain multiple project files).
If I can overcome this problem by modifying build process (for example by adding some flags to `xcodebuidl` command) it should be fine, but I prefer when everything is defined in `CMakeLists.txt` files.

[image: Xcode project Capabilities view]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the property `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME`, which is a boolean.

Set that property on your macOS target, e.g.

```
set_property(TARGET target PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME YES)
```

Or if you provide more properties for the target it might look like this:

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME "yourTargetName"
    MACOSX_RPATH TRUE
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.host.target
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS "@loader_path/Libraries"
    RESOURCE "${RESOURCE_FILES}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME YES
)
```

Comment: nice. Thanks. I have nice improvement for that.

Comment: is this `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME` somewhere documented? [Google failed to find anything](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+%22XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME%22).

Comment: `ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME` is the Xcode project attribute. You can see this from the "Build Settings" page of the project. Select any project attribute and in the "Quick Help" pane check the "Declaration" section. `XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_<an-attribute>` is the cmake syntax for setting Xcode attributes. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute.html#prop_tgt:XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_<an-attribute>

Comment: Thanks. I like to have full picture. This is really helpful.

Comment: @TheNextman I think there is a mistake in your second example (at least with xcode 11). Using **TRUE** for XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME will in fact generate **NO** in xcode project. The correct value to set for the attribute is **YES** (again, at least in xcode 11).

Comment: @Chris actually my answer was edited by another user - the original answer did specify `YES`. You are quite right of course and I've corrected the edit. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Chris this must be difference in `cmake` version (Xcode can't see this detail, Xcode project file simply contains own version of boolean value). I've added second part of answer (as I'm OP) and `TRUE` still works for me (had to make sure that after I've read your comment). I'm using `cmake` `3.20` and I'm sure it was working with version`3.5` so check your version of cmake.